# jQuery: $(document).ready(function() {function1(1)}); - how to stop performing function1 when variable exceed some value?

Tags: function, jquery, document-ready

The link blinks 5 times on the page when the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function1(1);
//some more functions
});


function function1(hide){
if((hide<10)){
    if (hide%2==1){
        $('.myclass2').css("color","black");
    }
    else{
        $('.myclass2').css("color","white"); 
    }
    hide = hide+1;

}
else{
  //some code to stop performing of this function. 
}
setTimeout("blinks("+hide+")",300);
}.
```

As result, class myclass2 blinks 10/2=5 times by 300ms. Once variable hide reaches 10, the function1 is doing nothing (just checks if (hide<10) for unlimited number of times recursively). 
P.S. 
Does it make sense to stop performing function1?
If yes, then how?

Important: .ready() contains not just function1, but another functions as well. They should keep working.

Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I think I've found the solution! if (hide<10) {setTimeout("blinks("+hide+")",30*hide+100);}. So it will not last forever. However, how to exclude that function from .ready()?

Comment: Why do you want to exclude the function from ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var blink =  setInterval("function1(1)",300);
    //some more functions
});
```

and to end the function:

```
clearInterval(blink);
```

Comment: Sorry, but that way it will not blink, since you’re always passing 1 into the function.

Comment: Set a global variable and update it rather than passing it through the function.

Comment: Yes, it works after setting a global variable. I had the same question as scravy, but then I guessed where to declare blink variable. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As function1 creates a new Timeout to call itself again and again, simply move that Timeout-creation info the if-clause so that it only fired when “hide < 10” is true. That way it won’t perform again.

Yes, I guess it *does* make sense to stop the function from executing again and again, if it does not do anything.

Your code would now look like this:

```
function function1(hide){
if((hide<10)){
    if (hide%2==1){
        $('.myclass2').css("color","black");
    }
    else{
        $('.myclass2').css("color","white"); 
    }
    hide = hide+1;

    setTimeout("blinks("+hide+")",300); // moved here
}
else{
  //some code to stop performing of this function. 
}
}.
```